# Spinner with fragment and MySQL database

Tags: android, mysql

This is the output image:

[image]

Currently I am working with a project of registration form. In that I used four `Spinner` and three edit text, but when I run the project the app is not getting in a correct order and when varying screen size the form is also changing. I want the app in a correct order and supported for all screen size. I used `Fragment` but that also is not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> listItems1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> listItems2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> listItems3 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Spinner sp, sp1, sp2, sp3;
EditText ed1, ed2, ed3;
Button b1;
String crop,state,cat,soil,GetpH, Getphos, Getpottas;
String DataParseUrl = "http://localhost/insert_agri.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  //  ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    BackTask bt = new BackTask();
    bt.execute();

    sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    BackTask1 bt1 = new BackTask1();
    bt1.execute();

    sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

    BackTask2 bt2 = new BackTask2();
    bt2.execute();

    sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);

    BackTask4 bt4 = new BackTask4();
    bt4.execute();


    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GetDataFromEditText();
            sendDatatoServer(crop,state,cat,soil,GetpH, Getphos, Getpottas);
        }
    });
}



private void GetDataFromEditText() {
    crop=sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
    state=sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    cat=sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    soil=sp3.getSelectedItem().toString();
    GetpH=ed1.getText().toString();
    Getphos=ed2.getText().toString();
    Getpottas=ed3.getText().toString();
}


private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ArrayList<String> list;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://........php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // Get our response as a String.
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            is.close();
            //result=sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray = jsono.getJSONArray("agriculture");
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                list.add(jsonObject.getString("crop"));
                //  list.add(jsonObject.getString("country"));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listItems.addAll(list);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.txt, listItems);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

My XML file also attaching with this.

activity_main

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tony.agri.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">


<TextView
    android:text="Enter Details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="136dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="136dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView15" />

<TextView
    android:text="crop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView16" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/spinner" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/spinner3" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner4" />

<TextView
    android:text="pH"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView20" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />

<TextView
    android:text="pospurs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView21" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="pottasm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView22" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText3" />

<TextView
    android:text="state"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="category"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_above="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="soil"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView15"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
```

spinnerlayout.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
```

Comment: You are using ScrollView and Spinner togerher and both have scrolling and scrolling of both views can bot run together

Comment: ok, after removing the scroll view, the app is not in correct format, how we can use fragment in this.

Comment: And Use Relative Layout in place of Linearlayout as Root layout.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace below code with your xml**

It would work for your design issues.. i am not able to understand yout order issue. please give me more details.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tony.agri.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
>


<TextView
    android:text="Enter Details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView15" />

<TextView
    android:text="crop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView16" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner3" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner4" />

<TextView
    android:text="pH"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4"
    android:id="@+id/textView20" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />

<TextView
    android:text="pospurs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView21" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2" />

<TextView
    android:text="pottasm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView22" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3" />

<TextView
    android:text="state"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView17" />

<TextView
    android:text="category"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView18" />

<TextView
    android:text="soil"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView19" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
```

Comment: thanks prathik. i tried it. its not working properly.

Comment: i attach a pic of what i really want, but while using this code it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the fixed size of text views and edit texts and use weight to get responsive design.
I make sure you will get layout or design according to your expectations.
if you need code then I can code also but you need to go through first because you will learn it.

Comment: how we can add weight for spinners?

Comment: <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_weight="xyz.xyz"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/spinner3" />

Comment: you firstly wrap all spinner into a linear layout and set weight sum and according to your expectation you can set if you want to make responsive width then you need to set 0dp width and weight = according to your expectation so go through it.